# fs.writeFile is not a function

Tags: javascript, fs

I have written a javascript program and I want it to be able to write data from an api call into a json file. For some reason the compiler keeps saying that fs.writeFile is not a function despite fs being required in.

code snippets:

```
var fs = require('fs')

function writeDataTofile(data){
   fs.writeFile("../transactionData.json",data,"utf8",function(err){
     if (err) return
   })
   console.log("file written")
 }
```

the data comes from here:

```
function getApiData(tx){
   console.log("api initiated")
//run chrome extension below to allow CORS:
//https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en-US
  var query = "https://blockchain.info/rawtx/"+tx+"/$tx_hash";
  request.get(query,function(err,res){
    var txValue = JSON.parse(res.text).out[0].value;
    var script = JSON.parse(res.text).out[0].script;
    var recipientAddr = JSON.parse(res.text).out[0].addr;
    fileData = res.text
    console.log(txValue, script)
      if(txValue != undefined && script != undefined){
        getValue(txValue)
        //scriptToAddress(script) //bitcore not working yet
        matchAddress(recipientAddr)
        writeDataTofile(fileData)
        return res.text
      }
      else{
        areConditionsMeet = false
      }
  })
}
```

Comment: The question has to be asked as you have not indicated via tags or in the question. Are you using node.js? or is this just in a browser. If you are in node.js then possible reasons could be that you have overwritten the `var fs` somewhere in your code, or there is a bad install of node.js. What is the value of `fs` just after the line var `fs = require("fs");` if its good there then must be over written elsewhere, if its bad then must be a bad install.